# How can I trigger ng-change when a space is entered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that is called when a textarea's value is changed.  It works great, except when the spacebar is pressed, then nothing is called.  Is there a way to activate this?  Technically, the content is changing, and I would like the function to be called regardless.

I am attaching a fiddle with the code.  You can see the `$scope.log` array does not push a new element when the spacebar is pressed (enter key as well), but it does with any other key that is not white space.

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UJWLN/4/

Comment: White space is automatically trimmed before the comparison is made. There's probably a workaround, but we'd need to know more about your use case.

Comment: Use case is almost exactly as outlined in the fiddle.  I am trying to call the function to make changes to other scope items when a key is pressed.

Comment: I meant why your app cared about the extra spaces.

Comment: I have a timer that counts down.  Every keystroke in the textarea resets the timer.  If someone hits enter twice and tabs, they only have a split second to get the first letter off, where they should have a couple seconds at least because they were typing.

Comment: Ultimately, I am just going to write my own directive to handle it and it should be no problem.  The ng-trim was exactly what I was looking for, but I think that down the road I may need more than just the trim functionality.

Comment: I just want to throw this out there, disabling trim can be seen as a bad practice in some organizations simply because you cannot copy&paste data that included an extra space. Standard copy&paste functionality includes the last space character :/ -- Just double click to highlight any word in this comment and you'll see what I mean. 
Just double check your use cases to make sure you want this feature.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the directive ng-trim in your input and set it to false, like this:

```
<textarea ng-change="changeFunction()" ng-model="myModel" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
```

But this won't work for every case. If you want something to be executed on every single keystroke, try with a custom directive. I wrote one for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/UJWLN/6/

```
myApp.directive('ngKeystroke', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            elem.bind("keyup", function(){
                scope.log.push('called');
                scope.$digest(); 
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 8):

To trigger `ng-change` event on space-bar also, I have used `ng-trim` . And it is working fine.

```
<textarea ng-model="myCtrl.content" name="content" ng-trim="false" rows="5" cols="15" maxlength="250"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Better try with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WVPDx/)

### `html`

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <textarea key-listener="changeFunction()" ng-model="myModel"></textarea>
    <div>{{log}}</div>
</div>
```

### `javascript`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.log=[];
    $scope.changeFunction=function(){
        $scope.log.push('Called');
    }
}

myApp.directive('keyListener', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        elm.bind("keyup", function(event) {
            scope.$apply(attrs.keyListener);
        });
    };
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone ever comes back to this.

I just read this in the documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D
ngTrim
(optional)

boolean

If set to false Angular will not automatically trim the input. **This parameter is ignored for input[type=password] controls, which will never trim the input.**

Answer (score 0):

For me the following code worked:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="typedEmail" ng-keyup="($event.keyCode == 32) ? validateEmail(typedEmail) : ''">
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.validateEmail = function(emailId){
 //Your Code goes here
};
```

*Event code 32: refers to the Spacebar key event code*
**Similarly**,
*Event code 13: refers to the Enter key event code*
*Event code 16: refers to the Shift key event code*
*Event code 17: refers to the Control key event code*
*Event code 18: refers to the Alt key event code*

Just refer the [ng-key](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) documentation, you try out the keyCode values there (down in the example in the angular doc).