# $scope ngModel does not always add tabs in textarea / input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm basically having trouble where my ng-model connected value is not being updated when I insert a tab into the textbox. Do you know how I would be able to have ng-model pick it up?

I created a codepen that describes my situation and allows you to reproduce the issue:

http://codepen.io/thinkbonobo/pen/mEyrmj

```
<textarea ng-model="myText"></textarea>
```

Here's how you can reproduce the issue.

1. Try inputting a tab after Hello
   It should produce the following under text: Hello\t
   Instead it just produces: Hello
2. The tab works if you put a nonwhitespace character after the tab. 'hello a'.
   You should see: Hello\ta.
3. Finally, try inserting another tab right before 'a'
   You should see: Hello\t\ta
   Instead you see only 1 tab: Hello\ta

Comment: Thanks for looking @JoseRocha. Did step 1 work for you as it should? also you may have done step 3 by pressing <tab><tab>a instead of just pressing <tab>a, clicking out then going back to right before a and pressing <tab>. Are you able to reproduce it now?

Comment: Ok the tab it is not assuming as key for trigger the change value. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282942/angularjs-ng-change-and-spacebar) should lead you in the right direction